# Show that exists some $m\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $\|T^mv\|\le\epsilon\|v\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Im not completely sure that the proof is correct. In particular the part 2) seems hard to describe correctly (but it seems correct). Then I have two questions: it is the proof below correct? It can be written in a better way (particularly the part 2)? Thank you.

---

This is the exercise 16 in page 192 of *Linear Algebra Done Right* third edition.

> Let $V$ a complex finite-dimensional inner product vector space, $T$ an operator in $V$ and $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ it holds that $|\lambda|<1$.
>
> Show that exists some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $\|T^mv\|\le\epsilon\|v\|$ for all $v\in V$.

We knows that exists at least one eigenvalue for $T$, because $V$ is a complex finite-dimensional vector space.

1) Suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then clearly exists some $m\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ such that $\|T^mv\|\le\epsilon\|v\|$ for any chosen $\epsilon>0$.

2) Claim: if $v$ is not an eigenvector of $T$ then exists some $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ such that $T^nv$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Proof: suppose that such $n$ doesnt exists, then $v$ belongs to some proper invariant subspace of $V$ under $T$, namely $U$.

But $U$ is also a complex finite-dimensional vector space and $T|_U$ is an operator on $U$, so it have at least one eigenvector. Then (recursively) if $v$ is not an eigenvector of $T|_U$ and such $n$ doesnt exists then it belongs to some proper invariant subspace of $U$ under $T|_U$, namely $S$.

A recursive argument, due to the finiteness of the dimension of $V$, show (by infinite descent) that such $n$ exists.

3) Choose an orthonormal basis of $V$ defined by $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$. Then, by 1) and 2), for every orthonormal vector $e_k$ exists some $m_k$ such that $$\|T^{m_k}e_k\|\le\epsilon\sqrt n$$

for some chosen $\epsilon>0$ and $n:=\dim V$. Then setting

$$m:=\max\{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n\}$$

we have that

$$\left\|T^m\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\|^2=\left\|\sum_{k=1}^n\langle v/\|v\|,e_k\rangle T^m e_k\right\|^2\le\epsilon^2 n,\quad v\neq 0\implies \|T^mv\|\le\epsilon\sqrt n\|v\|,\quad v\in V$$

where we used the fact

$$\|v/\|v\|\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle v/\|v\|,e_k\rangle|^2=1\implies |\langle v/\|v\|,e_k\rangle|\le 1,\quad k\in[n]$$

$\Box$

---

#### EDIT:

After some attempts I think I found a correct proof. Let $A$ an upper-triangular representation matrix of $T$ respect to some orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ of $V$ (we knows that such $A$ exists because $V$ is a complex finite-dimensional vector space).

Then we can set

$$A:=B+C$$ where $B$ is a diagonal matrix and $C$ is a matrix such that $C_{j,k}=0$ if $j\ge k$. Then

$$A^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\sum[B^kC^{m-k}]\tag1$$

where $\sum[B^kC^{m-k}]$ is a shorthand that means *sum over every possible different multiplication ordering of $k$ matrices $B$ and $m-k$ matrices $C$*. It is easy to see that there are $\binom{m}{k}$ different ways to multiply this set.

By assumption $|B_{j,k}|\le \lambda\,\delta_{j,k}$ where $\delta_{j,k}$ is the Kronecker delta and $\lambda\in(0,1)$, thus for each $\epsilon>0$ exists $m\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$|(B^m)_{j,k}|\le\epsilon,\quad j,k\in[n]\tag2$$

Now observe that $(C^2)_{j,k}=0$ when $j+1\ge k$. And by induction $(C^h)_{j,k}=0$ when $j+h-1\ge k$. If $\dim V=n$ then $C^n=0$.

Also observe that regardless of the multiplication order of $k$ matrices $B$ and $m-k$ matrices $C$ we have that

$$|(B^kC^{m-k})_{j,h}|\le \alpha^k(X^{m-k})_{j,h},\quad\alpha:=\max\{|B_{j,h}|:j,h\in[n]\}\tag3$$

where $\alpha<1$ by assumption and $X$ is a matrix defined by $X_{j,k}:=|C_{j,k}|$. Then for $\dim V=n$ and $m\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ we have that

$$|(A^{m n})_{j,h}|\le\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{m n}{k}\alpha^{mn-k}(X^k)_{j,h}\le M\alpha^{2+n(m-1)}(mn)^{n-1}\tag4$$

where we had set

$$M:=\max\{(X^k)_{j,h}:k\in\{0,\ldots,n-2\},j,h\in[n]\}$$

From $(4)$ is clear that

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}A^m=0$$

In particular this imply that for each $\epsilon>0$ exists $m\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$\|T^me_k\|\le\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt n},\quad \forall k\in[n]$$

Thus

$$\|T^mv\|^2=\left\|\sum_{k=1}^n c_k T^m e_k\right\|^2\le \frac{\epsilon^2}n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|c_k|\right)^2\le \frac{\epsilon^2}n\cdot n\|v\|^2,\quad v\in V$$

where we used in the last step a well-known inequality based in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the euclidean product in $\Bbb R^n$

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|\right)^2\le n\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^2$$

and the theorem

$$\|v\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle v,e_k\rangle|^2$$

$\Box$

Comment: I believe from the Schur decomposition of $T$ it's fairly easy to see that $T^m\rightarrow0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Thoth I dont follow exactly... I know that $T$ have an upper-triangular matrix representation for some orthonormal basis because $V$ is complex finite-dimensional. But from here how I can follow?

Comment: Your claim 2 is not true. Consider a $2\times 2$ matrix $A=[1/4 \: 0;0 \: 1/2]$.  Then $A^n[1;1]$ is never an eigenvector.

Comment: The question above makes a serious error in quoting the exercise from the book. First, the information that $V$ is an inner product space has been omitted. Second, and more serious, is that the quantifier on $\epsilon$ has been misquoted. The question should state "Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$", not "for some $\epsilon > 0$".

Comment: @Sheldon ah... sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: @Michael thank you very much. I will work in a different approach.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but doesn't it follow by induction that $$\| T^{m} v \| = |\lambda|^{m} \|v\|$$ where $\|v\|$ is finite. As $|\lambda| < 1$ we have that $\lim_{m \to \infty} |\lambda|^{m} \to 0$, so $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $$\| T^{m} v \| = |\lambda|^{m} \|v\| < \epsilon \|v\|$$?

Comment: @Mattos if $v$ is an eigenvector yes, but the exercise is about all $v\in V$, not necessarily eigenvectors.

Comment: @Masacroso As a start, what if you consider the special case of matrices and consider a matrix $A$ that can be written $A=D+N$ where $D$ is purely diagonal with all entries $d_{ii}$ having magnitude less than 1, and $N$ is nilpotent?  Consider $A^m = (D+N)^m = D^m + ...$.

Comment: @Masacroso Ah, I didn't read the question properly. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the Jordan normal form of some matrix representation $\mathcal{T}$ of $T$. Remember a version of the theorem states $\mathcal{T}$ is similar to a matrix of the form $D+N$, where $D$ is diagonal, $N$ is nilpotent, and they commute. For large $m$, what does $\mathcal{T}^m$ look like, in terms of $D$ and $N$?

Comment: thank you, but I dont know (by now) what is the Jordan normal form of a matrix.

Comment: This hint is unlikely to lead to a proof because the Jordan form cannot necessarily be obtained with respect to an orthonormal basis. Without an orthonormal basis, norm computations are difficult.

Comment: The usual operator norm with some pretty basic estimates $($like ${\lVert D \rVert}_{\infty}< 1$ and ${\lVert N \rVert}_{\infty}\leq 1)$ does the job.