# Show $\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}T^nv=0\iff |c_i|<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Suppose $T$ is a linear operator on a complex vector space $V$ and $(c_1,...,c_k)$ are the not necessarily distinct eigenvalues of $T$. Show that $|c_i|<1\iff T^nv\to 0$ for all $v\in V$.

My attempt: Since $V$ is complex, $T$ has a Jordan form $J=\begin{pmatrix}J_1 & 0 &...& 0\\ 0 & J_2 &... & 0\\ & & ...\\ 0 & 0 &... & J_k\end{pmatrix}$  where $J_i$ is a Jordan block for $c_i$. Now for all $n$,

$J^n=\begin{pmatrix}J_1^n & 0 &...& 0\\ 0 & J_2^n &... & 0\\ & & ...\\ 0 & 0 &... & J_k^n\end{pmatrix}$. For large enough $n$, each $J_i^n=\begin{pmatrix}c_i^n & 0 &...& 0\\ 0 & c_i^n &... & 0\\ & & ...\\ 0 & 0 &... & c_i^n\end{pmatrix}$ is diagonal. So for any $w\in V$ with coordinate vector $[w]=\begin{pmatrix}w_1\\w_2\\...\\w_N\end{pmatrix}$ (where dim$(V)=N$), we have $J^n[w]$ has $j-th$ entry $\sum_kc_k^nw_j$. So as $n\to\infty$, $J^n[w]\to 0$. Since $A=P^{-1}JP$ for some invertible $P$, letting $w=Pv$, we have $A^n[v]=P^{-1}J^n[Pv]=P^{-1}J^n[w]\to P^{-1}(0)=0$ as $n\to\infty$.

I think this argument works in proving both directions. Does this look correct? Thanks.

Comment: Why is $J_i^n$ diagonal for large enough $n$?

Comment: you are assuming here that $T$ is diagonalizable, that is, that $k=\dim V$. I tried a different proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333053/show-that-exists-some-m-in-bbb-n-s-t-tmv-le-epsilon-v) (not sure if correct).

Comment: @carmichael561 Ah, you're right. I was thinking nilpotent part is zero for large enough $n$.

Comment: One direction is particularly simple: if $|c_i| \geq 1$ for some $i$ and $v_i$ is the associated eigenvector, then $T^n v_i = c_i^n v$, which does not tend to 0. For the other direction, there is a neat analytic approach. If $T$ is diagonalizable, then the proof is quite easy. If $T$ is not diagonalizable, then by density there is some sequence of diagonalizable operators $T_k$ approaching $T$ (in any norm you wish, since we are in finite dimensions). I leave you to finish it off.

Comment: I think you can adapt your attempt to instead show that $J_i^n\to 0$ for each Jordan block.

Comment: Jordan form is not needed here. Instead, use the result that for some basis of $V$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to that basis is an upper-triangular matrix (this result is much simpler than Jordan form). Furthermore, the entries on the diagonal of that upper-triangular matrix are precisely the eigenvalues of $T$, repeated according to multiplicity. If $V$ is an inner-product space, then the basis can be taken to be orthonormal (just apply Gram-Schmidt in case it is not).